# InfluxDB '_internal' Database non existant

Tags: database, influxdb

I want to run InfluxDB on my Windows machine. I downloaded the neccessary files from this link: https://github.com/adriencarbonne/influxdb/releases/download/v0.9.0-rc11/influxdb_v0.9.0-rc11.zip

When creating a database everything works fine.

When I try to write to the created Database I get a *500 Server Error*.

I noticed that the command *SHOW DATABASES* only lists my  Database and not the _internal Database.

```
> SHOW DATABASES
name
mydb
```